# If Scott Allen can make it work ... why can't I? Should be a simple drop down list - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, drop-down-menu

I have been wrestling with what should be a very simple thing for weeks now. I simply want to create a dropdownlist in asp.net mvc 3 razor html page and I want the data for the dropdownlist to come from a model.

My Model is as follows which is in the Models.Project namespace.

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        CategoryId = 0;
        Name = "";
        Description = "";
        //Categories = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        Entities _db = new Entities(); //ef4
        CateogoriesList = from c in _db.Categories 
                        orderby c.Name
                        select c.Name;
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<string> CateogoriesList;

}
```

My Controller action is as follows

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Models.Project.Project proj = new Models.Project.Project();
    return View(proj);
}
```

My Razor view has the following relevant code ...

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model Models.Project.Project


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit Your Request</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor( Model => Model.CateogoriesList  )</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList( Model.CateogoriesList ) )
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send for RFP" /></p>
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error ...

`Compiler Error Message: CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'`

I saw the following clip make it work with the ViewBag ... and I don't understand why it won't work when I include the list in the model.

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

I have also seen that there are a lot of people that seem to have trouble with this simple task but in my googling ... I haven't come across anyone with the same error in trying to create a drop down list.

I would appreciate any suggestions that you or anyone may have. The only thing that I've come up with is that the `SelectList` constructor takes a parameter of type `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and what I'm trying to pass it is S`ystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` ... or something close to it ... and I don't know how to cast it appropriately ... though I don't think I should have to ... if it works with a viewbag as the means of transportation why doesn't it work with the model as the means of transportation?

Thanks,

EDIT:======================

The problem was to do with the type of object the selectList constructor would accept. For some reason it wouldn't accept a generic IQueryable but when I cast the result from the entity framework using the cast extension method toArray it suddenly worked.

So my model becomes ...

public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {

```
    Riebro.RiebroEntities _db = new Riebro.RiebroEntities();
    CategoriesList = (from c in _db.Categories 
                    orderby c.Name
                    select c.Name).ToArray<string>();
}


[Display(Name = "Choose a category")]
public string[] CategoriesList;
```

}

note the .ToArray on the end of the query and then suddenly

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(Model.CategoriesList))
```

works. Though I am going to point out the Model keyword here seems to be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your code, what's that? that's the reason cause the error.

```
  <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor( Model => Model.CateogoriesList  )</div>
```

correct one

```
      <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor( Model => Model.CategoryId  )</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true);

<fieldset>
    <legend>Submit Your Request</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.CategoryId )</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(Model.CateogoriesList) )            
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send for RFP" /></p>
}
```

Here is my simulation of your entity. I just add another CategoriesList2 which use to simulate the IQueryable object, but it's still working.

```
    public class Project {
    public Project() {
        CategoryId = 0;
        Name = "";
        Description = "";
        //Categories = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        //Entities _db = new Entities(); //ef4
        //CateogoriesList = from c in _db.Categories
        //                  orderby c.Name
        //                  select c.Name;
        //IQueryable<string> categoriesList = (new string[] { }).AsQueryable();
        CateogoriesList = new string[] { "abc", "def", "hij", "klm" };
        CategoriesList2 = (new string[] { "abc", "def", "hij", "klm" }).AsQueryable();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string[] CateogoriesList;

    public IQueryable<string> CategoriesList2;

}
```

Here is the view by using the IQueryable categories list

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Project


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Submit Your Request</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.CategoryId )</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(Model.CategoriesList2) )            
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Send for RFP" /></p>
}
```

Comment: Hi Vincent That's not the problem either. I made the modification as you suggested but that's not it. The problem is specifically on this line @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(x.CateogoriesList))

Comment: Hi, kevin, you didn't watch the video carefully or that video doesn't have label for that dropdown listbox. I've created your demo on my local machine. My answer is correct. Please read my answer carefully, you can either remove that label to see whether it's working or not. Otherwise I can send u my test project which has everything exactly same to your one(except I use string array instead of IQuerable for categoriesList). After change label for to CategoryId, it's all working. See my reply with new code

Comment: HI Vincent ... He definitely uses a different type to create the drop down list with. I'm retrieving the data from the database using entity framework 4. So I naturally get an IQueryable object. If the problem is with the type that I am using ... how do I cast an IQueryable<string> to a simpler object that the drop down list constructor can accept? The following query is how I'm retrieving the data ... CateogoriesList = from c in _db.Categories 
                            orderby c.Name
                            select c.Name;

Comment: So the answer was specifically around the type of object that the SelectList constructor would accept. I will edit my original post with the answer.

Comment: Glad to see you finally get it working. I just make another try, there is nothing wrong with the type, even you return IQuerable, it's still working. I will post my code in my answer section.

Answer (score 6):

In your view you use:

```
@model Models.Project.Project
```

whereas in your controller action you pass:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Riebro.Models.Project.Project proj = new Riebro.Models.Project.Project();
    return View(proj);
}
```

Notice the difference? `Models.Project.Project` vs `Riebro.Models.Project.Project`. You don't seem to be using the same type on your controller as on your view.

Also notice that it is bad practice to use namespace names that contain the name of a class.

Another remark is about using the Model keyword in lambda expressions:

```
@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.CateogoriesList)
```

You shouldn't use this keyword. Replace Model with something else.

Comment: Hi, the difference between my controller and my view was a mistake in my post. I've corrected it. I was trying to simplify it without adding the extra level that is really just a name and doesn't mean anything.

I've checked and what I pass from the controller to my view and the model I specify in my view are identical. 

I've also changed all my "Model" words to "x" so instead of ....

@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.CateogoriesList)

I have ...

@Html.LabelFor( x => x.CateogoriesList  )

Comment: I also tried it for the actual drop down which is where I get the compile error.

@Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(x.CateogoriesList))

but I am still left with the same problem.

Compiler Error Message: CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error but I still am.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the reserved keyword Model in your lambda expression

```
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor( Model => Model.CateogoriesList  )</div>
```

try this

```
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor( m=> m.CateogoriesList  )</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

I have tried the suggestion as mentioned in the comment above but it did not work. I believe the problem lies on the actual line that I create the drop down list.

Comment: if you still get the same error i would check if you use the keyword Model anywhere else in your code the wrong way

Comment: Thanks Geertvdc, I'm actually not using the keyword Model anywhere in my view at the moment. It doesn't even appear once except for in the @model statement.